# Sproutcore issuing errors on starting

Tags: sproutcore

I am new to sproutcore, and have installed the sproutcore properly as explained in the tutorial, including from rvm, to ruby 1.9.2 to all the gems dependencies. But whenever, i am issuing any sproutcore command, it throws me this error.

```
sproutcore server fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:223:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable sproutcore (Gem::Exception)
        from /home/love/.rvm/gems/gems/sproutcore-1.8.2/bin/sproutcore:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/sproutcore:19:in `load'
        from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/sproutcore:19:in `<main>'
```

Hope, if some one can solve, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the 1.8.2 gem that was fixed and pushed up as 1.8.2.1

Just run `gem update sproutcore` to get the latest version.

Check the blog update for more details: http://blog.sproutcore.com/sproutcore-1-8-2-released/